# Finding a segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I just need another pair of eyes to help me point out a silly mistake I surely made.

Struct and prototype:

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *orderedInsert(Node *p, int newval);
/* Allocates a new Node with data value newval
   and inserts into the ordered list with 
   first node pointer p in such a way that the
   data values in the modified list are in 
   nondecreasing order as the list is traversed.
*/
```

Function:

```
#include "orderedList.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Node *orderedInsert(Node *p, int newval){
       struct node* new = NULL
       new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       struct node* last = p;

       while(1){
          if (p == NULL){
             if (last == p){
                return 1;
             }
             new->data = newval;
             new->next = NULL;
             break;
          }
          if ((last->data <= newval) && (p->data >= newval)){
             new->data = newval;
             new->next = p;
             break;
          }
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

I get a segmentation fault when calling orderedInsert with any parameters.

Comment: AHHH!!! Don't use `new` as a variable name in C. You'll confuse everybody who's ever touched any C++.

Comment: True enough, didn't think of that, It just was quickly switched from node so it wouldn't be node* node =...

Comment: So `orderedInsert` is supposed to return a `Node *` but the only returns you have return either `1` or `0`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `struct node *node`. The names are in different spaces.

Comment: Yeah, I had just changed it to be less confusing in the post, and Shafik got it, I was returning an int as a Node.

Comment: @Mysticial Who cares? C and C++ are different languages. There are a lot of other things to get confused about, like "Why isn't the modulo operator operating identically?". If you think of them as different programming languages, you won't get confused. Don't cast malloc. You'll confuse everybody who *actually knows* C.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Unfortunately, I *don't* think of them as separate languages. I consider C++ to be a practical superset of C. And I doubt I'm the only one.

Comment: @Briland Your code doesn't even compile, for me. How are you getting a segfault from code that isn't valid C? I get "prog.c:14:25: fatal error: orderedList.h: No such file or directory", and when I fix that I get "prog.c:19:5: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘new’" because you're missing a semi-colon, and when I fix that I get "prog.c:25:14: error: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]", because you're returning `1` from a function that is supposed to return a `Node *`... On top of that, there is no `main`. What is the go with this horrible testcase? Fix it!

Comment: @Mysticial `char *foo = malloc(0);` <--- There's proof that you're wrong. Want more? `struct flexible_array_member { size_t size; int array[]; };` More? `size_t x = 42; int VLA[x];` More?...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour You missed the word "practical" in my last comment. And yes, I know very well the differences between C and C++ thank you very much.

Comment: @Mysticial No. You misused the word "practical". "Practical" means "Of or concerned with the actual doing or use of something". When I use C, I use VLAs, implicit `void *` conversion, and "`new`" as a variable name. Those are real life examples of valid C code that are invalid in C++. In order for C++ to be a superset according to the one and only definition of "superset", it must support ALL valid C code.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I'm not going to continue this argument anymore because it's not going to be constructive. You heard what I said already, and if you insist on being so pedantic about, then I will leave before this escalates into an all out flamewar.

Comment: @Mysticial Bjarne Stroustrup was asked in [his FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html), "Is C a subset of C++?", to which the first sentence he wrote was "In the strict mathematical sense, C isn't a subset of C++". I might be a pedant, but 1. I'm correct and 2. I'm *not* a moron... I can be relieved about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on your feedback your issue is that instead of returning a `Node *` from `orderedInsert` you are returning either a `1` or a `0` which if the calling code tries to dereference will cause a `seg fault`. As Lee pointed out there are other issues such as the fact that you are not actually properly inserting the new node.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the function itself is segfaulting, it's probably in the calling code that you're not showing us. Though there are a couple of obvious errors here. The most obvious is that it's not in fact inserting anything. This function makes the new node, but it never alters the existing list in any way, so the node is orphaned. Second, it's declared as returning a pointer but it returns 0 or 1. This won't segfault, but if the caller is expecting a pointer and dereferences it that way, you will.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I don't know exactly why it was segfaulting but when i fixed the returns and the fact that when p was null because the list was blank to start off with the while didn't even run completely it seems to work, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed semicolon in declaration of `struct node *` "new" pointer. Your method implementation is prone to memory leaks due to its returning values.

Actually, when talking about that method, it is clearly that it will never produce a segmentation fault. Most of the time this method will be looping till you shut down the process running it.

There are three "use cases" of this routine:

1. Call `orderedInsert(NULL,/* whatever */)` and get `Node *` at `0x00000001` adress;
2. Allocate space for the `struct node` type variable either on the stack or heap and call `orderedInsert(/* newly allocated variable pointer */,/* value */)` but make sure the `->data` of your freshly allocated variable is equal to `value` you pass into. For this instance your method returning null-pointer. Period;
3. Call `orderedInsert(/* Non-null */,/* not equal to "data" */)` and enjoy your code looping all the time.